# Is writing parcelable objects in a bundle that fast?

Tags: android, performance

I wanted to estimate the time needed to write a parcelable object in a bundle. I created my own parcelable class (with only two attributs : an int and a String) and I wrote a short application that instanciates 500 000 objects of my parcelable class, puts them into an ArrayList, writes the ArrayList in a bundle, and reads the ArrayList from the same bundle.

I was very surprised to see that writing and reading this quite huge list is instantaneaous. (0ms every time)

Can such an ArrayList be written "instantaneously", or am I doing it wrong?

```
    ...

    private static final int TEST_SIZE = 500000;

    ...

    mList = new ArrayList<MyParcelableClass>();
    for(int i=0; i<TEST_SIZE; i++){
        mList.add(new MyParcelableClass(i));
    }

    ... 

    Bundle testBundle = new Bundle();

    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();        
    testBundle.putParcelableArrayList("test", mList);        
    logTime("parcelableArrayList writing");
    //parcelableArrayList writing 0ms       

    ArrayList<MyParcelableClass> deserialization = new ArrayList<MyParcelableClass>();      
    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();        
    deserialization = testBundle.getParcelableArrayList("test");               
    logTime("parcelableArrayList reading");
    //parcelableArrayList reading 0ms


    private void logTime(String msg){
         long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime;
         log(msg + " " + String.valueOf(time) + " ms");
    }   

    private void log(String msg){
        Log.i(TAG, msg);
    }
```

Comment: show your logTime method :)

Comment: Indeed, this could help!

Comment: ok, no bug there... ;) have you tried setting the count higher (or adding more fields to parcable in MyParcelableClass). i read parcable is fast, but 0ms seems a bit too fast. ;)